# Create an Azure ActiveDirectory tenant for Azure Germany Cloud (MCD)

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-mcd

I want to create a second tenant in my subscription in my Azure Germany Account. I need it for testing reasons like in https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-multitenant-openidconnect// step 5.

As I understand, this is done usually in https://manage.windowsazure.com/. But this seems not to work in Azure Germany, because when I try to login there it gives me an error. When I want to open https://manage.windowsazure.de there is nothing as well as on https://manage.microsoftazure.de/.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *don't* need to create a second subscription. You can create an AAD in MCD *without* a subscription here:

https://account.windowsazure.de/organization

Comment: If you abandon the sign-up process halfway through, you will result with an Azure AD tenant created, but I would not really recommend using this approach to create test tenants. Completing the sign-up process will ensure the tenant "lives". Else, there is a small risk that it will be deleted because there is no service associated with it.

Comment: @PhilippeSignoret I agree with you that this is not an ideal / supported solution especially for a production AAD. However, I use this method to create test tenants without any issues and I do recommend it if you don't wan't to create a second subscription. But it's a good point worth mentioning!

Comment: :) I did this by accident yesterday. great answer, good to know.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you need to sign up for a second subscription in order to get a second Azure AD tenant.

Comment: thanks, i guess you are working for MS!? Then it is the right answer?!

Comment: There is another way, see my answer ;-)

Comment: The link you refer to is the sign-up page for a free trial of Azure Germany Cloud. If you complete that sign-up, then you are signing up for a second subscription.